# Is there an equivalent of Python's dir() in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Coming from a Python background, one thing that I really miss Python's dir() which lists out all of the methods in an object or library.

Is there an equivalent in Elixir ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on the terminal, you can type: `ModuleName.` and then press tab and it will show all available functions/macros in that particular module. There isn't something library wise though.